# How do you set In Video Promotion on a Youtube channel with a CMS account via the API?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I'm trying to set the in video promotion on a channel via the v3 data API as a CMS user.

If I do this as the channel owner user, then it works fine with the API and testing on the API docs.

However, I am trying to do this via a CMS user. Neither through the site https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/update nor Python code am I able to do this - I get a 403 back every time.

1) Is what I'm trying to do actually possible? i.e. can a CMS user modify a linked channel, or for updates do I have to be logged in as the channel owner on the API?

2) If 'yes' to point 1, what am I missing to make this work? I have the same working 'body' and 'part' from when I log in as the channel owner, but that just gives me 403's when trying to run it as the CMS user.

I see references to a 'onBehalfOfContentOwner' - is this the secret sauce to make this actually work? And if it is, what should go here? I've tried both the user name and YouTube user id's here for both the CMS user and the channel user, and it seems to make no difference - I still get a 403 every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, using an OAuth 2 token associated with a CMS user and setting the `onBehalfOfContentOwner` parameter is the way to make YouTube Data API v3 calls via delegation. What you're attempting does work for many Data API v3 methods, but updating InVideo options is not currently supported via delegation. (The documentation does not make this clear.)

Unfortunately, I don't have any information to share at this time as to whether delegation support will be added to InVideo options at some point in the future.